# $M/IM$ finitely generated $\Rightarrow$ $M$ finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ a left $R$-module and $I$ a two-sided ideal in $R$. $M/IM$ is a left $R$-module via
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> r\cdot (m+IM)=rm+IM \quad \text{ for } r\in R, m\in M.
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Assume $M/IM$ is generated by $\{\bar{m_1}, ..., \bar{m_t}\}$ as a left $R$-module. Let $m_i\in M$ such that $\bar{m_i}=m_i+IM$ in $M/IM$.
>
> Show that $\{m_1,...,m_t\}$ generates $M$ as a left $R$-module.

I already found a proof for this [here](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/commalg/fgmodule.html) but it uses Nakayama’s Lemma. I'm trying to prove this without this lemma.

My ideas so far:

Let
$$\begin{align}\varphi: M\rightarrow M/IM, \quad m\mapsto m+IM.
\end{align}$$

Take $m\in M$. Since $M/IM$ is a finitely generated left $R$-module, there exist $r_1,...,r_t \in R$ such that

$$\begin{align}
\varphi(m)&=r_1 \bar{m_1}+...+r_t \bar{m_t}\\
&=r_1(m_1+IM)+...+r_t(m_t+IM)\\
&=r_1m_1+...+r_tm_t+IM.
\end{align}$$

Then $m-(r_1m_1+...+r_tm_t)\in IM$ and thus, it exists an $a\in I, n\in M$ such that

$$\begin{align}
m=r_1m_1+...+r_tm_t+an.
\end{align}$$

And that's the point where I don't know what to do next.

What could I do next? Am I even on the right track?

Comment: This is of course wrong unless $I$ is specified.

Comment: What properties should $I$ have so that this is correct? Or is it impossible to say this in general?

Comment: Well, Nakayama's Lemma tells us that this holds when $I$ is contained in the Jacobson radical of $R$. You can find the proof everywhere. And you should also be able to find counterexamples when $I$ is an arbitrary ideal.

Comment: I don't think this is true even using Nakayma's Lemma.  One of the hypotheses of Nakayama is that $M$ is finitely generated.  Eisenbud explicitly comments on this on p. 124 of his commutative algebra book: "It is tempting, but in general wrong, to use Nakayama's lemma
to prove that a module $M$ is finitely generated by exhibiting finitely many
generators for $M/IM$."

Comment: The link you provided only proves this for the case where $R$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $I$ and $\{\bar{m_1}, ..., \bar{m_t}\}$ generate $M/IM$ as a vector space over the residue field $k = R/I$.  I am quite sure the result is false in general.